# IEEE Access latex file forces the volume and year to be listed as volume 4 2016, how do I change that?

Tags: footnotes, ieeetran

When compiling the latex template for IEEE access file, it forces the content in the bottom of each page to be "Volume 4, 2016". How do I change that?
See code below:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subfig}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 2019.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2019.DOI}

\title{BLA}
\author{\uppercase{R D}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}}
\address[1]{BLA)}
\tfootnote{This work was supported in part by CMC Microsystems for the provision of software tools.}

\markboth
{R.D \headeretal: BLA}
{R.D \headeretal: BLA}

\corresp{Corresponding author: RD (e-mail: BLA).}

\begin{abstract}
BLA
\end{abstract}
%...etc
 \end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of the compiled pdf]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where did you get the IEEE Access class files?

Answer (score 4):

The year value is hardcoded in the class, which is a bit odd. However, you can patch the footer commands with the `etoolbox` package to insert a custom macro. The volume is controlled by defining `\thevol`, which works without patching.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%% Define variable values
\def\thevol{3}
\def\myyear{2019}
%%% Patch the footer commands
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@evenfoot}{2016}{\myyear}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@oddfoot}{2016}{\myyear}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 2019.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2019.DOI}

\title{BLA}
\author{\uppercase{R D}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}}
\address[1]{BLA)}
\tfootnote{This work was supported in part by CMC Microsystems for the provision of software tools.}

\markboth
{R.D \headeretal: BLA}
{R.D \headeretal: BLA}

\corresp{Corresponding author: RD (e-mail: BLA).}

\begin{abstract}
BLA
\end{abstract}
abc
\EOD
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This code not change the first page. Please advise

Comment: @mohamedbadr the code above outputs only one page, where the volume and year are printed correctly. Also, when I add some content in the code above to output two pages then the volume and year are printed on both pages, so I'm not sure if I understand your comment. If you can make a minimal example of a document with two pages that does not show the correct behavior then you can ask a new question about that using the `Ask Question` button on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the volume and year easily like below in your tex file :

```
\renewcommand{\thevol}{15}
\renewcommand{\theyear}{2020}
```

However, the year might not change as the IEEE access style class `ieeeaccess.cls` has mistakenly used hard coded year instead of using this `\theyear` variable.

In that case, you can find the 2016 word in your `ieeeaccess.cls` file and replace with `\theyear`. Do not change the `\def\theyear{2016}` line in the `ieeeaccess.cls` file though :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code before the \begin{document} tag. It has compiled for me perfectly. The output obtained from the below code is given in the screenshot below:
[image]

Here we have not changed the volume of the journal. this should be changed by the editing team of the journal. However, the latest year can be changed as there will be no current volumes for the previous years.

```
% FIX FOR ADDING CORRECT VOLUME AND YEAR AS IEEE ACCESS DEFAULT FORMAT IS SHOWING VOLUME 6, 2016. THE VOLUME XX NEEDS TO BE CHANGED TO THE CURRENT VOLUME IN THE BELOW LINE
% FIX for VOLUME AND YEAR STARTS HERE
\def\THEYEAR{2022}
\gdef\thevol{XX}
\makeatletter
\ifjtehm
  \def\headerlogo{\raisebox{-2pt}{\includegraphics[width=7.61pc]{jtehmLogo.png}}}
  \def\ps@titlepage{%
     \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]{\raisebox{5pt}%
       {{\titlepageheaderfont\color{accessblue}\headName}}}%
       \hfill\headerlogo\mbox{}\vspace*{-3.5mm}\par\rule{30.54pc}{.3pt}}}
     \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]\mbox{}\headerlogo%
       \hfill{\raisebox{5pt}{{\titlepageheaderfont\color{accessblue}\headName}}}%
       \vspace*{-3.5mm}\par\mbox{}\hfill\rule{30.54pc}{.3pt}}}
     \def\@oddfoot{\raisebox{3pt}{%%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont\@pubid}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footerpagefont\@artnum}}}%\hspace*{1.8pc}
       }}
     \def\@evenfoot{\raisebox{3pt}{%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footerpagefont\@artnum}}\hfill\mbox{}}\hspace*{1.8pc}%\hspace*{-1.8pc}
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont\@pubid}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}}}%
     }}
  }
% normal page
  \def\ps@headings{%
     \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]{\raisebox{5pt}%
       {\headerfont\rightmark}}\hfill\headerlogo\mbox{}\vspace*{-3.55mm}\par%
       \rule{30.54pc}{.3pt}}}
     \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]\mbox{}%
       \headerlogo\hfill{\raisebox{5pt}{\headerfont\leftmark}}\vspace*{-3.55mm}\par%
       \mbox{}\hfill\rule{30.54pc}{.3pt}}}
     \def\@oddfoot{\raisebox{8pt}{%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footerpagefont\@artnum}}}%\hspace*{1.8pc}
       }}
     \def\@evenfoot{\raisebox{8pt}{%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footerpagefont\@artnum}\mbox{}\hfill}}%\hspace*{1.8pc}%\hspace*{-1.8pc}
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}}}%
     }}
  }
\else
  \def\headerlogo{\raisebox{-2pt}{\includegraphics[width=7.61pc]{Logo.png}}}
  \def\headerlogoall{\raisebox{-2pt}{\includegraphics[width=7.61pc]{notaglineLogo.png}}}
  \def\ps@titlepage{%
    \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]\mbox{}\nheaderfont\color{accessblue}\headName\hfill\headerlogo{\raisebox{-2pt}{\,}}\color{black}\vspace*{-1.5mm}\par\hrulefill}}
    \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]\mbox{}\headerlogo\hfill\nheaderfont\color{accessblue}\headName{\raisebox{-2pt}{\,}}\color{black}\vspace*{-1.5mm}\par\hrulefill}}
     \def\@oddfoot{\raisebox{3pt}{%%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont\@pubid}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footerpagefont\thepage}}}%\hspace*{1.8pc}
       }}
     \def\@evenfoot{\raisebox{3pt}{%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footerpagefont\thepage}\hfill}\mbox{}}\hspace*{1.8pc}%\hspace*{1.8pc}
       \hspace*{-1.8pc}\hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont\@pubid}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}}}\hspace*{1.8pc}% [updated here]
     }}
  }
% normal page
  \def\ps@headings{%
     \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]{\raisebox{-2pt}{\headerfont\rightmark}}\hfill\headerlogoall\mbox{}\vspace*{-1.5mm}\par\hrulefill}}
     \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-6.3mm]\mbox{}\headerlogoall\hfill{\raisebox{-2pt}{\headerfont\leftmark}}\vspace*{-1.5mm}\par\hrulefill}}
     \def\@oddfoot{\raisebox{8pt}{%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}\hfill\mbox{}}}%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footerpagefont\thepage}}}%\hspace*{1.8pc}
       }}
     \def\@evenfoot{\raisebox{8pt}{%
       \hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{{\footerpagefont\thepage}\mbox{}\hfill}}\hspace*{1.8pc}%\hspace*{-1.8pc}
       \hspace*{-1.8pc}\hbox to 0pc{\hbox to \textwidth{\mbox{}\hfill{\footervolfont VOLUME\ \thevol, \THEYEAR}}}\hspace*{1.8pc}% [updated here]
     }}
  }
\fi
\pagestyle{headings}
\makeatother
% FIX for VOLUME AND YEAR END HERE
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove VOLUME 4,2016 from the Access template. Edit ieeeaccess.cls file. Open the file and search for VOLUME, the value of volume(eg: 4), and value of year (eg:2016). Remove all these values from the ieeeaccess.cls file. This works!

Comment: I would not change official template. If OP attend to publish in journal, which use this template, the publisher will adjust this data to datum when article will be published.

Answer (score -2):

Open the latex class ieeeaccess, find the 2016 and change it to 2020

Comment: There are two things wrong with this answer.  First is a problem caused by the creator of the class file -- unless the article is actually accepted and published by the journal, identifying a purported volume and issue is unethical.  The publication's editorial staff should be notified about the problem.  Regarding changing a class file, even though it is to be used only by whoever makes the change, if the file escapes into the wild, it can cause serious confusion.  Don't do it.